# get the class name by another class name jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div  having many classes , let suppose

```
<div class="myDiv one two three"></div>
```

Now I want to get the class names using the class "myDiv", here are some cases , in some cases I need the class name which is on third position i.e "two", In some times I need class on position second which is "one", can any one have idea to get my desired classes.
My jQuery code is

```
alert($('.myDiv').attr('class'));
```

But this alert all the classes.

Comment: The order of class names can change if manipulated by script... so it might be better to rethink the solution

Comment: Try splitting by an empty space: `' '`

Comment: I assume once you have the required class, you ought to do something with the element? try **[`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)**. So `if ($('.myDiv').hasClass('one')) { // do Something }`.

Comment: required class is myDiv.

Comment: the others classes are dynamic , there for I want to get their names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can accept use dom elements, it has [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) which may be what you want.

> - Element.classList
>
> elementClasses is a DOMTokenList representing the class attribute of
>   elementNodeReference. If the class attribute was not set or is empty
>   elementClasses.length returns 0. element.classList itself is
>   read-only, although you can modify it using the add() and remove()
>   methods.

```js
alert($('.myDiv')[0].classList[2]);
// Get the count of the classes
var length = $('.myDiv')[0].classList.length;

// Get last class from the list.
alert($('.myDiv')[0].classList[length - 1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv one two three"></div>
```

Comment: Remember that classList is [available at IE10+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist) only.

Comment: I need to check it on only ff, chrome and safari.

Comment: I think there's a polyfill that will make it work lowest to IE8.

Comment: How would I get the last class name with out knowing the number of classes? any idea

Comment: `classList` has read-only attr `length`, so you can use `length - 1` to get the last element.

Comment: Thanks @fuyushimoya for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try     [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
$( ".mydiv" ).hasClass( "foo" );
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  
  var classNames = $('.myDiv').attr('class').split(" ");
  
  alert(classNames[0]);
  alert(classNames[1]);
  alert(classNames[2]);
  alert(classNames[3]);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv one two three"></div>
```

You can do something like this. I dont think there is any way of getting class names by index.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `String.split(' ')` ?

```
var classes = $('.myDiv').attr('class').split(' ');
alert(classes); // myDiv,one,two,three
```